# Angular6 getting error when building site for production

Tags: angular6, production-environment

I was using Angular: 6.0.3 and when I updated my angular using npm update I am getting error when I am trying to build site for production.

When I am running command:

```
ng build --prod
```

I am getting error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property '_statSync' of undefined
```

Current angular version is: 6.1.10

Full error you can see it here:[Full error report link](https://gist.github.com/Shakir-Ali-t9l/d9f61f83f190ca12188c991e59a26f2d)

Comment: Can you update your question with package.json file's data. I think the error is generated due to cache loader version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because of the version of cache-loader in package.json file. just run `npm update` and you will get cache-loader 1.2.5 they have fixed this in updated version.